# can't get return value in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have following tutorial how to request value from `node js` and return back to user requested but not successful.

here my javascript code..

```
put('id','coment',function(data) { 
        var obja = JSON.parse(data);
        var items = Object.keys(obja);
        items.forEach(function(item) {  
            alert(obja[item].field1); //its no result value     
        });                         
})
function put(id, data, callback) { //call from here to nodejs
        $.ajax('http://localhost:8000/' + id + '/', {
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) { if ( callback ) callback(data); },
            error  : function() { if ( callback ) callback(false); }
        });
    }
```

and here my nodejs

```
connection.query("SELECT field1,field2,field3 from table", function(e, row) {
                    if(e)
                    {
                        console.log('An error occured: '+e)
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        try{                        
                            res.write(JSON.stringify(row));  //send value back to user requested
                            res.end();
                        }catch(ex){
                            console.log('errror' + ex) ;
                        }
                    }
});
```

in console, the query was load normally but when I try send back to user requested, it gets no value.

My problem is, why can't I **send back** to user requested?

Comment: are you sure `row` contains data? Try using `console.log` and see what is actually in `row`

Comment: You shouldn't need `var obja = JSON.parse(data);` because it will already be parsed because you set `dataType: 'json'`. Also do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: @ltvie Cool, I'll add an official answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need `var obja = JSON.parse(data);` because it will already be parsed by jQuery due `dataType: 'json'` being set.

Also based on the code you've shown `obja` is an `Array` so instead of this:

```
var items = Object.keys(obja);
items.forEach(function(item) {  
    alert(obja[item].field1);
});
```

Just do this:

```
obja.forEach(function(row){  
    alert(row.field1);
});
```